# "java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintWriter" when writing file - jenkins workflow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

We have a piece of workflow code that does these things:

1 Loads some files from disk

2.Renders their contents using a SimpleTemplateEngine and bindings

3.Writes their result to another files.

```
def renderTemplates(binding) {
  //stage "Render templates"
  sh "find $infraDir/*.tpl -printf '%f\n' > result"
  def files = readFile('result').split('\n')
  println("Found tpl files -> $files")
  sh "rm result"  //Remove the result file

  for(int i=0; i<files.size(); i++){
    def tpl = files[i]
    println("Process tpl file ${tpl}")
    renderTemplate(readFile("${infraDir}/${tpl}"), tpl, binding)
  }
}

@NonCPS
def renderTemplate(String input,String tpl, binding){
  def template = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(input).make(binding)
  def rendered = template.toString()
  def newFileName = "$infraDir/${tpl.replaceFirst(/\.tpl$/, "")}"
  //sh "echo ${rendered} > ${newFileName}" //--> GIVES ERROR
  writeFile file: newFileName, text: rendered // --> ERROR AS WELL
}
```

However, the workflow fails everytime with this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintWriter
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor97.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2434)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor394.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:132)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:371)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:355)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:309)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
in field locals
in field parent
in field parent
in field parent
in field caller
in field e
in field program
in field threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5fc05e47
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried using sh to echo to a file, but that fails too.
Tried removing @NonCPS, that too an error.

If I comment out the writeFile and sh lines, the workflow succeeds, but obviously the file is not written.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor`  instead, e.g :

```
// vars/tokenize.groovy

def call(String text, Map binding) {
    _tokenize(text, binding)
}

@NonCPS
def _tokenize(String text, Map binding){
    def engine = new org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor(binding)
    def s = engine.replace(text)
    engine = null
    return s
}

// in Jenkinsfile or another .groovy

def binding = [:]
binding.veggie = 'Carrot'

def text = "${veggie}"

writeFile file: 'veggie.txt', text: tokenize(text, binding)
```

Comment: I had the same problem as @punit-agrawal, this solution worked for me

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was simply moving from the SimpleTemplateEngine to GStringTemplateEngine. If you put it all on a single line then you do not need @NonCPS. Obviously you may still want to extract this as a separate method in line with software design principles but I just wanted to illustrate that it could be done in-line with the pipeline dsl

```
   stage() {
   def binding ....
   def template ...
   String result = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine().createTemplate(template).make(binding).toString()}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you shouldn't use any Pipeline built-ins (i.e. `sh` and `writeFile`) within `@NonCPS` annotated functions.
Try moving file writing out of func, like this:

```
@NonCPS
String renderTemplate(String input,String tpl, binding){
    def template = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(input).make(binding)
    return template.toString()
}
...

for(int i=0; i<files.size(); i++){
    ...
    String rendered = renderTemplate(...) 
    def newFileName = "$infraDir/${tpl.replaceFirst(/\.tpl$/, "")}"
    writeFile file: newFileName, text: rendered
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. taking it out does not work either. It still fails with the same exception.

Comment: Could you please put the whole pipeline in the question? At least the node block is missing.

Comment: I did some investigation of [SimpleTemplateEngine](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-templates/src/main/groovy/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.java#L152) code. It relies on creating and running another Script object which `out` is bound to a `PrintWriter`. I am not experienced enough to work it around. I'd suggest filling a ticket on [Jenkins JIRA](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and switch to another approach.

Comment: The SimpleTemplateEngine is now wrapped in a @NonCPS. so I am surprised it is still throwing a `Serialization` exception. - https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables


This is part of a remote script that is being called by workflows using a remote file loader.

Comment: I saw that it was wrapped. In my experiments it was wrapped too. That's it seems like a bug for me and I asked you to fill a JIRA for Jenkins dev.